# Why not put all class properties in an associative array for easy set/get/etc.?

Tags: php, arrays, class, oop

I have a class with 23 different properties of various types, but I'll only show three in this example. A typical way to construct this class would be:

```
class Item 
{
public $name;
public $price;
public $date;

// Getters and setters
public function get_name()  {return $name;}
public function get_price() {return $price;}
public function get_date()  {return $date;}
public function set_name($val)  {$name = $val;}
public function set_price($val) {$price = $val;}
public function set_date($val)  {$date = $val;}
}
```

With 23 different properties I would need 46 different set/get functions, and my code would have to call all these different functions by specific name, so it's difficult to create loops.

Can I do this instead:

```
class Item 
{
public $props = array (
 'name' => NULL,
 'price' => NULL,
 'date' => NULL
 );

// Getters and setters
public function get( $key )       { return $props[$key]; }
public function set( $key, $val ) { $props[$key] = $val; }
public function getKeys() { return array_keys( $props ); }
}
```

To get a property such as $name I'd simply use Item->get('name'); 
   rather than the specific getter function  Item->get_name();

This way, even if I have 23 different properties of different types, I still use only one getter and one setter for all of them. Plus, it's easy to loop through all (or a subset) of the properties by doing a foreach on the getKeys() array.

It seems so convenient I would think it would be a pretty standard format for PHP classes, yet in all the tutorials and examples of PHP classes that I've seen I have never seen this construct used. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: For starters, your properties are all `public` so why bother with getters / setters?

Comment: Forget the associative array, just define public properties on your class.

Comment: Just use `__get()` and `__set()` magic methods

Comment: If you use getters/setters then its easier to find bugs because php will complain when you misspell a name but if you use associative array and misspell a keyword, it wouldn't be that obvious to figure out.

Comment: Having 23 different properties on a class is a code smell imho; surely, you can apply grouping into separate classes.

Answer (score 2):

This is fine if you don't care what *type* your properties are or you don't care if they should be restricted to a certain set of known properties (ie, you don't care about encapsulation).

If however you want to use specific types, you will need some control.

```
class Foo {
    /**
     * @var Bar
     */
    private $bar;

    public function setBar(Bar $bar) {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }

    /**
     * @return Bar
     */
    public function getBar() {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}
```

The other real benefit to setters in particular is the ability to perform transformations on input data. For example

```
class Foo {
    /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    private $date;

    public function setDate($date) {
        if (!$date instanceof DateTime) {
            $date = new DateTime((string) $date);
        }
        $this->date = $date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> it's difficult to create loops.

What meaningful loop would you make over `name`, `price` and `date`?

The reason individual getters and setters are used is encapsulation: prohibiting things outside the class insight into its insides. For example, say you have `age` property. Then you extend your class with `birth_date` property. Then you think it would be a good idea to automatically calculate `age` instead of having to assign both values. If you have a getter for `age`, it is trivial: just have it stop returning `$props["age"]`, and start returning the difference between the birth date and now. But if you're not using the age getter but a direct access, you would have to change every single place in your codebase where you're accessing age.

Or say that you want to issue a log statement every time a property changes. Trivial to put it inside a setter, but you're screwed if you have a public property that anyone is allowed to mess with at will.